# Block Printing Web Pages in IE Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, windows-7, block

In an effort to reduce non-work-related printing, I am searching for a solution to prevent users on our network from printing Internet Web Pages unless they are from one of our company web applications. In other words, we want to maintain a "white list" of URLs that users are allowed to print from and block all other printing. I am looking for ideas how to approach this.

We are using Windows 7 and IE 11 throughout the enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this product. I'm not sure if it will suit your needs 100% but it was a product I was aware of that seems pretty decent enterprise solution for print management.

www.papercut.com

http://www.papercut.com/products/ng/manual/ch-printer-mgmt-filters.html

-Cheers